# Automatic date in Google Sheet data entry. I can apply the scenario I have found to 6 windows in the same worksheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have prepared such a scenario, but I want to use it in 6 pages like the question asked above.

```
function onEdit() {

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet

var r = s.getActiveCell();

if( r.getColumn() == 1 ) { //checks the column

var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);

if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?

nextCell.setValue(new Date());

}

}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] What do you mean by "like the question asked above"? Also please show what you tried.

Comment: @Ruben I think the OP's words _like the question asked above_ isn't a reference to another (linkable) question on stackexchange, but is merely repeating the long-winded question - the OP wants their code to apply to six sheets rather than just one. Or at least, that's my reading ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your `onEdit` script currently applies to a single sheet (`Sheet1`). You want the script to apply to six sheets.

Replace line 5

- `if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) {`
  with
- `if( s.getName() == "Sheet1"  || s.getName() == "Sheet2" ||  s.getName() == "Sheet3"  || s.getName() == "Sheet4" ||  s.getName() == "Sheet5"  || s.getName() == "Sheet6" ) {`

If your sheet names are different, then edit script so that the sheet names are the same as in your spreadsheet.

In Google Apps script the logical operators used with `if`  statement include:

- `&&`: meaning "AND"
- `||`: meaning "OR"

In this case, the `IF` statement will allow the code to execute if the sheet name is "Sheet1" OR "Sheet2" OR "Sheet3", and so on.